# Why is question closed with only two close votes?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

This [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/26685/13494) was closed with only two close votes.  I have not participated very long on Writers SE.  I'm familiar with other SE sites that require five close votes.

Two seems like a very small number.

Comment: Moderators can close questions without any additional close votes. We usually prefer to let the community close things, but there are situations where it makes sense for a moderator to act quickly. I'll let @Standback speak to why in this case but my guess is it was to prevent any further answers while the question is edited.

Answer (score 4):

The second close vote came from a moderator, and moderators can close (or reopen, or delete, or undelete) unilaterally.  The moderator who closed it left comments explaining the problem and asking the author to edit; with luck it won't be on hold too long.  "On hold" isn't meant to be forever, but in this case the question was unclear and it's not a good idea to have people guessing about what was meant when answering.

Comment: *"On hold" isn't meant to be forever* -- that is very interesting.  On other sites I participate in, the "on hold" questions almost never get manually deleted.  Here it's different?

Comment: @aparente001 it's not *meant* to be forever, but a question being put on hold usually means that the author needs to make an edit (for example, to clarify something that was put on hold as unclear).  Too often, authors see the hold and think that's the end, so they don't make the edit, so the question does get closed and eventually deleted.  I'm trying to counter that sense of doom.